# Format cells in row conditionally based on the first cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to reference a cell outside the "Applies to" area in a conditional formatting formula?
I have a small table in which I would like any blank cells to be highlighted *only* if the first cell of the respective table row is *not* blank. The first cell should never be highlighted.

I would rather not use Visual Basic, if I don't have to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you sure can. You can use the formula:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A$1)),ISBLANK(A2))
```

Where the first row is in `1:1`, `A2` is the active cell.

Comment: Thank you. I just figured it out a moment ago. My formula was roughly `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A1)),ISBLANK(A2))`.

Comment: @user2554661 Glad to have helped :)